# How to sort my Docker images by size with `docker images` command?

Tags: docker, sorting, terminal

To see all the images I have installed, I run `docker images`. I'd like to sort all my images by "SIZE". How can I do this? More generally, how does one sort the returned images by any parameter, such as "CREATED"

Answer (score 99, accepted):

**docker images**  supports **--format** flag to customize output -> https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/images/#format-the-output

Adding custom formatting and using **sort** does the trick:

```
docker images --format "{{.ID}}\t{{.Size}}\t{{.Repository}}" | sort -k 2 -h
```

Comment: Including the tag if you have different versions of the same image and want to identify them: `docker images --format "{{.ID}}\t{{.Size}}\t{{.Repository}}:{{.Tag}}" | sort -k 2 -h`

Comment: Why pass a custom `--format` flag when size is already included as column 7 by default? See comments on @Michel Samia's answer below

Comment: **Hint**: `sort -h` does not respect decimal point in numbers, or do I miss something?

Comment: As @ralph mantioned above this doesn't sort properly because of decimal points...

Comment: `sort -h` here (on Rocky 9, e.g., same as RHEL 9: `sort (GNU coreutils) 8.32`) only works if there is no space between the unit and the number. I.e., the unit of `500MB` would get recognized, but `500 MB` would be just a number (not a megabyte).

Comment: This does not seem to work properly for example for sizes ranging vom `1GB` to >= `10GB`. For example: `10.5GB` will be above `1.08GB`.

Answer (score 47):

None of the answers correctly show how to sort the actual `docker images` command.

Here is a bona fide solution:

```
docker images | sort -k7 -h
```

---

Note: it's the 7th, not 5th column, because we have to skip additional 2 spaces created by the time unit and "ago" (e.g. to sort by "1.8GB"
rather than by "weeks" in: "name tag hash 7 weeks ago 1.8GB"). This trick was first posted in one of the comments under [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60846535/9962007).

Comment: This doesn't sort properly when there are numbers with decimal points.

Answer (score 6):

```
docker image ls --format "{{.Size}} {{.ID}} {{.Repository}}:{{.Tag}}" | LANG=en_US sort -h | column -t
```

```
# sample output
1.24MB 5ba631491225 busybox:latest
206MB  8ce5afe3d430 registry.hub.docker.com/gentoo/portage:latest
974MB  d06781d69b4c registry.hub.docker.com/gentoo/stage3:systemd
1GB    d13df3eacaa7 gentoo-distrobox:latest
24GB   e7512ebcf557 ghcr.io/fabceolin/windev:usb
```

Comment: Seems to be the only answer which sorts correctly when floating points are involved

Comment: Bonus track:
`docker container ls -s -a --format "{{.Size}} {{.Names}}" | sed -r 's/\(virtual .*\)//' | LANG=en_US sort -h`

Comment: Actually these 2 seem to have issue sorting it correctly, too.
E.g.

149MB  a
2.14MB  b
327MB  c
64.8MB  d
688MB  e
71.7MB  f

Comment: I ended up writing a python script:
`docker images | python3 -c "import sys; from humanfriendly import parse_size; print('\n'.join(sorted(sys.stdin.read().strip().split('\n')[1:], key=lambda x: parse_size(x.split()[6]))))"`

Comment: Guys this is the correct one!

Answer (score 5):

Logical solution should be

```
docker images | sort -k5 -h
```

but this doesn't work, because docker emits spaces instead of tabs.

Created issue for that(https://github.com/docker/cli/issues/2406).

If you have time and know go, please contribute the fix :)

Till fixed, you can use some wrapper script like https://github.com/pixelastic/oroshi/blob/master/scripts/bin/docker-image-list

Comment: It's not because of tabs that do not work. It's because the 5 (fifth) column it is not size, it is a part of the CREATED column.

Comment: This sorta works: `docker image ls | sort -k7 -hr`

Comment: A locale-independent command (because a floating-point char) is:
`docker image ls | LANG=C sort -k7 -hr`

Comment: None of these works correctly, if floating points are involved. Not even Fabricio's one

Answer (score 2):

If using PowerShell, you can sort by arbitrary fields such as repo/image name as follows:

```
docker images --format="{{json .}}" |
    ConvertFrom-Json |
    Sort-Object Repository |
    Select-Object Repository,Tag,ID,CreatedSince,Size |
    Format-Table
```

though sadly it doesn't work well on human-readable fields such as `Size` so it unfortunately doesn't answer the more specific first part of your question.

Comment: I think size is only human readable when printed. I was able to sort using it. See my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71959947/1814970 (tried to suggest an edit here, but SO didn't allow).

Comment: Ah that's good to know, perhaps an improvement in Docker since I posted this originally!

Answer (score 1):

*Tried to suggest an edit, but SO didn't allow me, saying that the queue was full.*

Building on [@sparrowt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65221886/1814970) for a **PowerShell** solution, I believe `Size` is only human readable when printed. So if you convert them to integer first, you can sort:

(This is the same code from the other answer, changing one line.)

```
docker images --format="{{json .}}" |
    ConvertFrom-Json |
    # Sort-Object Repository |                    # ORIGINAL
    Sort-Object Repository, { [int]$_.Size } |    # SORTING BY SIZE
    Select-Object Repository,Tag,ID,CreatedSince,Size |
    Format-Table
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the `--format` table according to the docker documentation of [docker-images](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/images/)

e.g. sort by repository name

```
docker images --format 'table {{.Repository}}\t{{.ID}}\t{{.Tag}}\t{{.Size}}' | (read -r; printf "%s\n" "$REPLY"; sort -h -k7)
```

**Output:**

```
REPOSITORY                               IMAGE ID       TAG                      SIZE
danieltobon43/pcl-docker                 06a35efdd8ec   1.0-alpine3.15-dev       1.56GB
danieltobon43/pcl-docker                 06a35efdd8ec   1.12.1-alpine3.15-dev    1.56GB
danieltobon43/pcl-docker                 39415115561c   1.9.1-ubuntu20.04        5.75GB
danieltobon43/pcl-docker                 7369903b06b3   1.0-alpine3.15           1.27GB
danieltobon43/pcl-docker                 d412b4ff42d5   1.12.1-alpine3.15        531MB
dbscan                                   6416b9ed2fa1   1.0-ubuntu20.04          2.1GB
dbscan                                   f3a4fd088d94   1.0-alpine3.15           1.32GB
ghcr.io/patrickhoefler/dockerfilegraph   93485687d9ab   0.7.3-alpine             44.9MB
github/super-linter                      385b056df558   latest                   6.35GB
myapp                                    8ccfe15f0ebd   1.0                      71.9MB
pcl-docker                               d412b4ff42d5   1.12.1-alpine3.5         531MB
pcl-docker                               e4b28f82aab5   1.12.1-v1.2-alpine3.15   594MB
vtk-docker                               aacf6a38b5ff   8.1.0-alpine3.5          1.11GB
```

Answer (score 0):

To sort by any column set `sort_column` to the number from `1` to `4`.
To sort descending set `desc` to `1`

```sh
sort_column=4 && \
desc=0 && \
delim="$(printf '\t')" && \
{ \
    printf "REPOSITORY:TAG${delim}IMAGE ID${delim}CREATED${delim}SIZE\n" && \
    docker images --format "{{.Repository}}:{{.Tag}}${delim}{{.ID}}${delim}{{.CreatedAt}}${delim}{{.Size}}" | \
    LC_ALL=C sort -t"$delim" -k"$sort_column" -h \
    $([ ${desc:-} -eq 0 ] || echo "-r"); \
} | \
column -t -s"$delim"
```

Same code as a one-liner:

```sh
sort_column=4 && desc=0 && delim="$(printf '\t')" && { printf "REPOSITORY:TAG${delim}IMAGE ID${delim}CREATED${delim}SIZE\n" && docker images --format "{{.Repository}}:{{.Tag}}${delim}{{.ID}}${delim}{{.CreatedAt}}${delim}{{.Size}}" | LC_ALL=C sort -t"$delim" -k"$sort_column" -h $([ ${desc:-} -eq 0 ] || echo "-r"); } | column -t -s"$delim"
```

**Example sort by `SIZE`** **Descending**

`sort_column=4`

`desc=1`

```
REPOSITORY:TAG      IMAGE ID      CREATED              SIZE
android-sdk:latest  08eeb5aa5e29  2022-01-22 21:14:23  1.1GB
node:13.8.0-buster  f6de44b06e1f  2021-12-21 22:28:44  910MB
debian:buster       58075fe9ecce  2020-09-30 02:33:47  114MB
ubuntu:bionic       d27b9ffc5667  2019-03-12 01:21:12  65MB
hello-world:latest  4ab4c602aa5e  2018-10-11 21:21:30  1.9kB
```

**Example sort by `REPOSITORY:TAG`** **Ascending**

`sort_column=1`

`desc=0`

```
REPOSITORY:TAG      IMAGE ID      CREATED              SIZE
android-sdk:latest  08eeb5aa5e29  2022-01-22 21:14:23  1.1GB
debian:buster       58075fe9ecce  2020-09-30 02:33:47  114MB
hello-world:latest  4ab4c602aa5e  2018-10-11 21:21:30  1.9kB
node:13.8.0-buster  f6de44b06e1f  2021-12-21 22:28:44  910MB
ubuntu:bionic       d27b9ffc5667  2019-03-12 01:21:12  65MB
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a hard time figuring out the keys, but have found `jq` to be very helpful to quickly get this kind of stuff done. E.g.:

```
$ docker images --format json | jq -r 'unique | sort_by(-.Size) | .[] | [ .Id[:12], .Size, .CreatedAt, .Names[] ] | @tsv'
5cffd02133cb    915590610       2023-02-11T03:24:34Z    docker.io/library/ruby:latest
9124e6ec78cc    886347105       2023-02-11T03:37:24Z    docker.io/library/ruby:2.7
6a658e3ed635    513900464       2023-01-24T15:17:16Z    docker.io/pipelinecomponents/ansible-lint:latest
1de5905a6164    416218073       2022-11-30T23:30:42Z    docker.io/library/mariadb:latest
68f5d950dcd3    386595867       2022-11-15T06:38:54Z    docker.io/library/postgres:latest
1403af3b6d4a    308156195       2021-08-06T18:32:44Z    docker.io/library/golang:1.15-alpine
818ca3531f99    264457584       2023-04-04T18:26:39Z    docker.io/library/golang:1.20-alpine
eeb6ee3f44bd    211690387       2021-09-15T18:20:23Z    docker.io/library/centos:7
63f107ef819e    203491339       2022-12-19T23:20:28Z    docker.io/library/rockylinux:8.7        docker.io/library/rockylinux:8
ce99dcf19c24    181691319       2022-12-22T02:41:17Z    docker.io/library/rockylinux:9.1        docker.io/library/rockylinux:9
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the above two approaches by @sparrowt and @marcelora what ended up working for me was

```
       docker images --format="{{json .}}" |
       ConvertFrom-Json |
       Sort-Object {$_.Size/1KB} |
       Select-Object Repository,Tag,ID,CreatedSince,Size |
       Format-Table
```

It seems that the $_.Size/1KB part was of importance in my scenario

Without it I would receive errors like

> Cannot convert value "xGB" to type "System.Int32". Error: "The input string 'xGB' was not in a correct format."

Do note that my answer is almost completely derived from the above two answers with small changes which ended up helping me out personally.

Answer (score 0):

Other approach, using python

```
docker images | python3 -c "import sys; from humanfriendly import parse_size; print('\n'.join(sorted(sys.stdin.read().strip().split('\n')[1:], key=lambda x: parse_size(x.split()[6]))))"
```